# Difference between "./" and "sh" in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

Sometimes i see that few scripts are executed through "sh" command and sometimes through "./" command.I am not able to understand the exact difference between them.Please help me out .

Comment: maybe also interesting: https://askubuntu.com/q/22910/354350

Comment: @Fidel provides a good answer, I do not have enough reputation to add an comment, but `. file` should be interpreted as sourcing a file. Using the word `executes` might create the misunderstanding that we directly executes it. >source or the equivalent but standard dot . do not execute the script, but read the commands from script file, then execute them, line by line, in current shell environment. from:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291404/why-does-bashs-source-not-need-the-execution-bit

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`sh file` executes a shell-script file in a new shell process.

`. file` executes a shell-script file in the current shell process.

`./file` will execute the file in the current directory. The file can be a binary executable, or it can start with a hashbang line (the first line of the file in form of `#!....`, for example `#!/usr/bin/ruby` in a file would signify the script needs to be executed as a Ruby file). The file needs to have the executable flag set.

---

For example, if you have the script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

TEST=present
```

and you execute it with `sh test.sh`, you'd launch a new `sh` (or rather `bash`, most likely, as one is softlinked to the other in modern systems), then define a new variable inside it, then exit. A subsequent `echo $TEST` prints an empty line - the variable is not set in the outer shell.

If you launch it using `. test.sh`, you'd execute the script using the current shell. The result of `echo $TEST` would print `present`.

If you launch it using `./test.sh`, the first line `#!/bin/sh` would be detected, then it would be exactly as if you wrote `/bin/sh ./test.sh`, which in this case boils down to the first scenario. But if the hashbang line was, for example, `#!/usr/bin/perl -w`, the file would have been executed with `/usr/bin/perl -w ./test.sh`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Although,i was able to run the .sh file through ./ without mentioning the hashbang line.How come it was possible ?

Comment: Without a hashbang line, `bash` will assume it is a shell script file. You do need a hashbang if you want to use any other interpreter.

Comment: most useful answer I've found

Answer (score 14):

In simple words, `sh file1` executing *sh command/executable* with *file1* as a parameter. In this case *file1 doesn't require execute privilege* as sh executable read and intercept the commands in the file.

`./file1` its nothing but running/executing an executable file *file1*, hence it requires executable privileges. In this case it executes on the shell mentioned in the shebang `#!/bin/sh` if its not mentioned then its on the current shell.

Hoping the above statements are not chaos :)

Answer (score 3):

With sh  , we can run a script that doesn’t have execute permission set on it, we run it as argument for sh, but ./ needs the permission as it is supposed to be an executable.
In both cases,  new shell will be created to run the script. See the below example:

```
root@ub18:~/shell# vi test1.sh
#!/bin/bash
my_var=hello
echo $my_var
#Shows the current shell processid
echo $$
root@ub18:~/shell# echo $$
1896
root@ub18:~/shell# sh test1.sh
hello
2093
root@ub18:~/shell# ./test1.sh
-su: ./test1.sh: Permission denied
root@ub18:~/shell# chmod +x ./test1.sh
root@ub18:~/shell# ./test1.sh
hello
2102
root@ub18:~/shell# ./test1.sh
hello
2103
root@ub18:~/shell# ./test1.sh
hello
2104
root@ub18:~/shell# sh test1.sh
hello
2106
```

Answer (score 1):

when your file is not executable you can't run using `./file_name.sh` normally you can run by `sh file_name.sh` if you change your file to executable `chmod a+x file_name.sh` you can run your file by `./file_name.sh`